# Pass client value to string.format in MVC Razor

Tags: model-view-controller, razor

I'm using MVC with Razor engine.

In my javascript, I would like to get a string like this:

```
    function TestFormat(element)
    {
            $("#divError22").text('@string.Format("You are using {0}", element.innerHTML)');
    }
```

How could I pass element values/parameter from client to @string.format?

Currently, the error is: `The name 'element' does not exist in the current context`

Please advice.

Comment: I am not getting you Why you want use Razor code in java-Scripts? instead of you have simple replace functionality in javascripts `$("#divError22").text("You are using replaceWord".replace("replaceWord",element.innerHTML));`

Comment: Any update on issue?

Comment: hi Hardik, the reason I used it because of using resource for multiple languagues. The sample above is just simple to people can understand.

Comment: please share your original code so I can help you asap to solve

Comment: add your original code so i can help you easily